# Matplotlib não funciona no VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, matplotlib, deep-learning

Estou tentando praticar um pouco sobre rede neural em Python, mas a matplotlib dá varios erros no VSCode

Esse é o inicio do algoritmo

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop\Linguagem Programacao\Rede Neural\AutoMPG.csv')
x=dataset[['weight']]
y=dataset[['mpg']]
```

[E essa é a mensagem no terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNVWO.png)

Comment: Instala a biblioteca PIL

Comment: A biblioteca PIL foi descontinuada em 2011, use a lib [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

Comment: O problema estava no arquivo csv a ser lido.